# Error starting "xampp" stack: I can not start stack

Tags: stack

Can anybody help me?
This error comes out

I have already tried entering the following code to the terminal and nothing.

rm -rf ~ / .bitnami / stackman

I have Big sur Version 11.3

error starting "XAMPP" stack

cannot calculate MAC address: Using fd 7 for I/O notifications
hv_vm_create HV_ERROR (unspecified error)

[error starting "XAMPP" stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8FBO.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking to resolve this error i solved my issue this way, this seemed to work for me and I tried all other methods using command line and older versions

Steps to reproduce:

1. download Xampp latest version
2. once downloaded and opened, navigate to manage servers.
3. click configure apache.
4. change the port to your port "8888"
5. open config file 'httpd.conf' and edit the port to your port eg.
   #Listen 12.34.56.78:8888
   Listen 8888

5b.
#ServerName [www.example.com:@@Port@@](http://www.example.com:@@Port@@)

## XAMPP

ServerName localhost:8888

6. repeat step 5 but for sql config file 'my.cnf' and for 'httpd-ssl.conf'giving them different ports
7. Restart the servers.